# Алгоритмы, Кормен. Помогите составить инвариант цикла

Tags: алгоритм, циклы

Книга Алгоритмы, автор Кормен. упражнение 2.1.3 Надо составить алгоритм линейного поиска в последовательности и составить инвариант, доказывающий корректность работы цикла.

Алгоритм на псевдокоде:

```
// i, n -целые числа, A[n] - целочисленный массив, v - то что ищем в массиве, отступы показывают принадлежность к верхнему уровню

// Первое сравнение в while нужно, если в массиве мы не найдем искомый объект, чтобы цикл посмотрел массив до конца, а второе сравнение, если вдруг искомый объект попайдется, выйти из цикла.

        i=1
        while i<=n and v!=A[i]
         i++

        if(v==A[i]) return i
        else return -1
```

Я придумал такой инвариант, но не уверен в нём:
Цикл сравнит все элементы массива в диапазоне [1..n-(n-i)].
Он равен true в начале, при каждой итерации. А вот при выходе из цикла я не уверен, правильно ли?

Помогите составить инвариант цикла (предложите пожалуйста свой вариант). Сам алгоритм рабочий. Я его переделывал под Си и запускал, всё работает прекрасно, но почему-то инвариант не могу составить.

Мда никто не знает...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для любого `k`: из `k < i` следует `v != A[k]`

На LaTeX'е : `$\forall k : k < i \Rightarrow A[k] \not = v$`

Картинкой:

[image: Инвариант]

PS. У вас кстати в коде ошибка, проверка `if(v==A[i]) return i` при отсутствии элемента выйдет за границы массива и у вас будет out of range, правильнее было бы так:

```
if(i <= n) return i
```

То есть после пробега цикла счётчик `i` остался в диапазоне, это значит, что мы выпали из цикла по второму условию, а не по первому. Если же мы выпали по первому, то элемента нет, `i` больше `n`, второе условие проверять нельзя - индекс вне допустимого диапазона (но зато попадание в диапазон проверить можно).

Comment: У меня проверка if происходит 1 раз, после работы цикла. Она к циклу не относится

Comment: Это не изменяет того факта, что она у вас ошибочная. Повторюсь - при отсутствии искомого элемента в массиве эта проверка у вас обратится вне допустимого диапазона индексов массива.

Comment: при отсутствии искомого элемента, функция вернет -1

Comment: Я всё же настаиваю, что мой первый комментарий насчёт ошибки верен. Попробуйте разобраться, если конечно это вам нужно. Функция вернёт -1, если только в "чужой памяти", куда вы залезете, не окажется случайно то значение, которое вы ищете. Вероятность этого мала, но всё-таки она есть. Но даже если бы это было невозможно, вы обращаетесь в массив по индексу, которого в нём не существует. Это UB, а значит может случиться что угодно, если бы, скажем, ваш массив был бы QVector'ом, то ваша программа просто аварийно завершила работу. Надеюсь, мои комментарии вам помогут.

Comment: Я так и не понял, какой тут инвариант. Вы не знаете?)

Comment: @MZ_ , а формула в моём ответе разве не подходит?

Comment: Спасибо а как вы нашли его? Мне интересен ход ваших действий для нахождения инварианта